# How can we tell if a press mold need more stages?

Tags: metals, molding, metal-folding

I was asked to design a simple press mold for a 0.5mm sheet metal part. It has some small but rather deep sinks (5-7mm) which has made me wondering if it can be done in a single stage or it needs more stages. I guess there should be a table to help me through without the hassle of FEM with Ansys or other softwares. I read some books on metal-forming but I couldn't find my answer.

[image]

Comment: Why wouldnt you just try it? I mean you can easily test this in one day with a simple hand operated hydraulic press to get ballpark figures.

Comment: Yeah... I'm working at home. Don't want to make an reason to be there.

Comment: This is mostly a question of how much force do you have, how many parts you want to make, is it cold or hot working and how much tolerance and plastic deformation you are willing to tolerate and what about your tool wear.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the ductility of the "sheet metal".Commonly steel or aluminum, but that is just part of the answer ; the particular alloy and condition/temper must be known . Also die life- number of parts to be made from a set of dies.And as commented, the force available in the press.

Comment: As I remember an aluminum alloy/condition needed to be developed to make the deep draw of the now very common aluminum beverage can.